# Set Insert trigger to store max value in another column

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

This is what my table looks like:

| student_id | subject_id | total | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 6 |  |
| 102 | 2 | 5 |  |
| 103 | 1 | 9 |  |
| 101 | 1 | 10 |  |
| 103 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 104 | 1 | 7 |  |

I want the "*max*" column to be automatically populated when the total is inserted.

Expected Output:

| student_id | subject_id | total | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 102 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 103 | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 101 | 1 | 8 | 10 |
| 103 | 2 | 2 | 7 |
| 104 | 1 | 7 | 10 |

I will like to create a trigger for this.

This is my SELECT statement which works fine but how do I put it in a trigger?

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT `subject_id`,MAX(`total`) AS MaxTotal
FROM results
GROUP BY `subject_id`
)
SELECT results.*,CTE.MaxTotal
FROM results
JOIN CTE ON results.`subject_id` = CTE.`subject_id`;
```

I did this but I got a plethora of errors

```
CREATE TRIGGER `max_score_before_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `results`
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.max = (WITH CTE AS (SELECT `subject_id`,MAX(`NEW.total`) AS MaxTotal
FROM results
GROUP BY `subject_id`
)
SELECT results.*,CTE.MaxTotal
FROM results
JOIN CTE ON results.`subject_id` = CTE.`subject_id`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference "*new*" inside a `BEFORE` trigger type. You may want to first
insert the row, then update the column with an `AFTER` trigger type:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `max_score_before_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `results`
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE     <your_table_name>
INNER JOIN (SELECT subject_id, 
                   MAX(total) AS total_max
            FROM <your_table_name>
            GROUP BY subject_id) cte
        ON <your_table_name>.subject_id = cte.subject_id
SET <your_table_name>.max = cte.total_max;
```

Note that this approach will update the previous columns too, as if you insert a new field that becomes the max, you may want to update the already existing rows too. If not, then you can use a condition inside the `UPDATE` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `max_score_before_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `results`
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE     <your_table_name>
INNER JOIN (SELECT subject_id, 
                   MAX(total) AS total_max
            FROM <your_table_name>
            GROUP BY subject_id) cte
        ON <your_table_name>.subject_id = cte.subject_id
SET <your_table_name>.max = cte.total_max;
WHERE <your_table_name>.student_id = NEW.student_id
  AND <your_table_name>.subject_id = NEW.subject_id;
```

Comment: when I set your trigger, I can't seem to insert scores anymore.

Comment: This trigger is meant to **update** your max value, not to insert new rows. It will automatically activate (trigger) when you are using an `INSERT` statement on that table. If you don't insert, the trigger doesn't update.

Comment: ok, but I was also looking to insert new rows. When they are inserted the max score column should also be gotten

Comment: I don't think there's any feature in MariaDB that supports insert statements that catch max values at the same time. You can do that only as two separate operations or maybe change DBMS that supports such thing. @MaryPebbles